# Append variable To string in php insert

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue appending a file name variable to a string in a sql insert like so

```
$insert = $mysqlConn->query("INSERT into images (image_name, url) VALUES ('".$fileName."', 'images/".$fileName."'");
```

I can do it with just the $fileName and it works fine but my syntax is wrong. I'm simply trying to make sure that every file name inserted starts with 'images/'

So if I'm inserting 'red.jpg' it would be 'images/red.jpg'

Comment: You're just missing the trailing `)` for the `VALUES`, change the string to `"INSERT into images (image_name, url) VALUES ('".$fileName."', 'images/".$fileName."')"`

Comment: You should parameterize your query.

Comment: You must use PDO for security reasons to prevent injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store image value into one variable

```
 $imgPath = 'images/'.$fileName;
```

Above variable you can pass into the query

Answer (score 0):

try this,you are missing one bracket

```
$insert = ("INSERT into images (image_name, url) VALUES ('".$fileName."', 'images/".$fileName."')");
```

Comment: Your closing parenthesis is on the wrong side of the quote.

Comment: Please don't post answers to questions which are just simple typos. Instead, make a comment (as I have already done) and flag the question as "off-topic" due to a typographical error. Questions like this add no value to the site and will eventually be deleted, thus causing you to lose any reputation that you may gain from answering.